# How to generate numbers in an array using rand()

Tags: c++

Instead of manually inputting the numbers in the array, how can i randomly generate these 10 numbers in an array? they can be in any location, just needs to be these 10 numbers

```
int array[length] = { 1000, 2000,3000,4000,5000,6000,7000, 8000, 9000, 10000};
```

Comment: Use [`std::random_shuffle()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle)

Comment: how to do i exactly use that?

Comment: See my answer please.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::shuffle` to permutate the positions of the numbers in your array randomly (adapted from the [reference documentation sample](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle)):

```
const size_t length = 10;
int array[length] = { 1000, 2000,3000,4000,5000,6000,7000, 8000, 9000, 10000};

std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 g(rd());

std::shuffle(std::begin(array), std::end(array), g);
```

After the `shuffle()` call the values appear at random positions in the `array`.

Comment: @user4581301 Must have been a _petit mal absence_ (not enough coffee perhaps), I finished it finally (1 hour laterz ;-P)

Comment: What is mt19937 g(rd());

Comment: A [standard random generator engine](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/mersenne_twister_engine).

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to use a non-library algorithm, you can switch each element of the array with another element located at a randomly determined position. In code, it looks like this:

```
int array[length] = {1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000, 6000, 7000, 8000, 9000, 10000};
srand(time(NULL));
int randompos, temp;
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
   randompos = rand % 10;
   temp = array[i];
   array[i] = array[randompos];
   array[randompos] = temp;
   //here, you could have a cout << array[randompos] << " "; to test
}
```